# LINQ: multiple JOINS without the long final anonymous variable using dot-notation

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query using dot-notation that has to make joins with several different enumerables. The way I found to do a multiple join is to do it one after the other: instead of something that would be the equivalent of the following SQL sentence:

```
SELECT
   blah blah blah
FROM
   tableOne as One, tableTwo as Two, tableThree as Three
WHERE
   One.fieldOne == Two.fieldOne AND
   One.fieldTwo == Three.fieldTwo AND
   One.fieldThree == something
```

it ends up something like:

```
SELECT
    blah blah blah
FROM
    (
      SELECT 
          blah blah blah
      FROM
          tableOne as One, tableTwo as Two
      WHERE
          One.fieldOne == Two.fieldOne
          One.fieldThree == something
    ) as firstJoin,
    tableThree as Three
WHERE
    firstJoin.fieldTwo == Three.fieldTwo
```

The .Join() in Linq looks like:

```
localTableOne.Join(localTableTwo,
                   One => One.fieldOne,
                   Two => Two.fieldOne,
                   (One, Two) => new { One, Two })
```

The problem I have is that, once I go into the second JOIN, the annonymous variable for the result of the previous JOIN result doesn't have a property "fieldOne" or "fieldTwo" or any of the fields of the local tables joinned. It has a property "One", that has the properties from the first table, and a property "Two", with the ones from table 2. So, if I want to join those results with another table, the lambda function for the inner table would look like

```
firstJoinResult => firstJoinResult.One.fieldOne
```

Which wouldn't be a problem if I only were joining three tables. I'm currently joining 7 tables. The Linq query ends with a .Select() function, so the lambda function's fields end up looking like:

```
fieldOne = seventhJoin.sixthJoin.fifthJoin.fourthJoin.thirdJoin.secondJoin.firstJoinResult.One.fieldOne
```

Is there any way I can make that call smaller? Someway to access the field I'm looking for directly? Another way to make a multiple join?

Thanks

**UPD**

I forgot to mention that I was looking for a solution using dot-notation Linq.

Comment: I would use the query syntax rather for joining multiple tables rather than chained calls to `Join`.

Answer (score 5):

using query syntax it would look like this

```
var query = from One in tableOne 
            from Two in tableTwo
            from Three in tableThree
            where One.fieldOne == Two.fieldOne
            where One.fieldTwo == Three.fieldTwo
            where One.fieldThree == something
            select new {
            };
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that I was looking for a solution using dot notation.

Comment: @Heathcliff: But *why* would you look for a dot notation solution? The whole point of query expressions is to make complicated situations like this simpler. You should use both forms, depending on which is most readable.